# SQL Server 2017 installation error: "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable error"

Tags: sql-server

[image: Message appearing when trying to install SQL Server 2017]

I'm installing SQL Server 2017 and get this error. Please help me!

Answer (score 8):

You installed SQL Native Client (or whatever product name is listed) with an MSI located on a network share at some time in the past.  SQL installer is trying to modify or update that install, but can't access the MSI.

Uninstall the listed product, then try the install again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I had to download and show the path to file manually. [Here is the link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135577) to download MS OLE DB driver. To download latest version search in google for "ole db driver" and in this window show the path to the file manually

Answer (score 0):

1.First you remove the exist Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client from Control
panel  “Add or Remove Programs”

2.Then download and install SQL Server 2012 Native Client newly to the machine

3.Try again the SQL Server 2017 installation